# Getting record with max date per user and inserting it to temp table - performance issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlperformance

I need to get the maxdate per useraccount from the statement table and insert into temp table. Statement tables have more than 40 million records. I tried the following query and it took more than 4 mins. Is there any better way to do this?

```
select useraccount, max(date)
into #temptable
from statement
group by useraccount
```

Comment: Does `useraccount` have an index?  Does `date`?  Beyond that ... "well, you say there are *40 million* rows ...!"  It just might *take* several minutes to do this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grouping can be expensive.  And 4 minutes does not seem that bad for processing and creating a large table.  But if you have an index on `(useraccount, date)`, you could try:

```
 select useraccount, date
 into #temptable
 from statement s
 where date = (select max(s2.date) from statement s2 where s2.useraccount = s.useraccount);
```

Comment: Using the `EXPLAIN` verb on the various alternatives might also give some insight as to which one will be better ...

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a nonclustered columnstore index with useraccount and date column as below

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX   [NCCIX_statement_useraccount_date] ON [dbo].[statement]
(
   [useraccount]
   ,[date]
)WITH (DROP_EXISTING = OFF, COMPRESSION_DELAY = 0)
GO
```